# Using RDS Aurora PostgreSQL, every second update query is not updating a field in the row correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, amazon-aurora

My every first query updates the subscription_id but every second query removes the subscription_id from the table even thought the payload for the query is same (with different subsciption_id but the payload always has a subscription_id). It shouldn't delete the value from the table for any query.

Using RDS Aurora PostgreSQL: 15.2

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "wallet" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES "user" (id) ON DELETE CASCADE UNIQUE,
    customer_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    subscription_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  );
```

Command:

```
await client.query('UPDATE "wallet" SET subscription_id = $1, updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE user_id = $2 RETURNING *',[subscription_id, user_id])
```

Response 1:

```
response.rows[0] = {"id":1,"user_id":1,"customer_id":"cus_OJNfP0Mu1EYale","subscription_id":"sub_1NqZVsJw0oI6B3daTpPVYntu","created_at":"2023-07-25T20:50:51.531Z","updated_at":"2023-09-15T09:44:42.161Z"}
```

[image]

Response 2:

```
response.rows[0] ={"id":1,"user_id":1,"customer_id":"cus_OJNfP0Mu1EYale","subscription_id":"sub_1NqZWBJw0oI6B3daGKkR98K1","created_at":"2023-07-25T20:50:51.531Z","updated_at":"2023-09-15T09:45:01.986Z"}
```

[image]

Expection:
It should update the subscription_id in both queries, instead of deleting the value of subscription_id in the second query.

Comment: Impossible to answer without the code. $1 is most likely empty (null) or containing an empty string ''.

Comment: I have added the data as well. $1 or $2 is never null or empty.
Let's take "subscription_id":"sub_1NqZVsJw0oI6B3daTpPVYntu" and "user_id" : 1.

I'll add the table schema as well in the question.